# Clickable phone number with pauses and bridge/extension in calendar event

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-3, calendar, phone-app

What's the proper way (if any) to format a phone number when entering it as the "Location" of a calendar event under ICS (4.0.4, Samsung Galaxy S3, AT&T) so it can be clicked and auto-entered into the dialer... including pauses and subsequent digits to dial an extension, conference bridge, PIN code, etc?

I tried creating an event with a Location in the form:

1-999-999-9999,,,123456789#

but when the event reminder actually came up and I clicked it, the only thing that ended up in the dialer was 123456789

Does ICS and/or Samsung use a different character for 'pause', do I have to somehow escape it with extra characters (quotes? parentheses? etc), or did Samsung and/or the ICS calendar/dialer team just screw it up (number+pause+moredigits is something that roughly half the calendar-dialer implementations I've seen just can't ever seem to get right for some crazy reason)

Answer (score 1):

I found this thread: http://forums.androidcentral.com/verizon-galaxy-s-iii/297744-calendar-event-how-add-bridge-numbers-easy-dial.html

It looks like you can make a contact with a complex dialing code and then link to that contact as an attendee on the calendar event. Then click the attendee link to dial the number.